# Why does flexible grid loose its flexibility when container is given a maximum size?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid container that generates a grid with as many `300px` columns as fit. It is also a flex item and is given `flex: 1` to fill its parent.

Note that flex items have a minimum size of `min-content` by default, not `0` like in Flow Layout. This creates a cyclic dependency because the minimum size of the container depends on the size of the grid, while the size of the grid depends on the size of the container.

However this doesn't seem to matter because the flexible grid columns reflow nicely. At least until I set a maximum size. As soon as I set a maximum size, the `min-content` doesn't recompute anymore, and stays at whatever size the grid had at that moment. In turn, the container doesn't shrink anymore and the grid doesn't recompute its columns.

Why is that?

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the problem. Shrink the screen size once for `max-width` enabled and once for it disabled. Once the columns reflow, and once not. This happens consistently in all major browsers.

```css
body {
   display: flex;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  /* vvvv TOGGLE ME vvvvv */
  max-width: 700px;
  /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `min-width:0`